# I would like to know if do I need to notify the URLs web-services (that my app accesses) in some file of the project

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, app-store

I'm developing an iOS app that accesses Web-Services, I would like to know if do I need to notify the URLs web-services (that my app accesses)  in any file of the project, for analysis during the app approval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to notify Apple about what services you are using or why.

In the company I work we have published many apps and never had a problem with this, so you can just consume them from your app without worrying about it